# autoprint failing when trying a test page

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to do an auto download

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Create PDF</title>
        <header>    
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/jspdf.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/addimage.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/from_html.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/ie_below_9_shim.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/svg.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/autoprint.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/ace.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ace/ace-master/lib/ace/ace.js"></script>
        <!-- Editor -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/editor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>        
        var doc = new jsPDF(); 
        // I know the proper spelling is colour ;)
        doc.setTextColor(100);
        doc.text("This is gray.", 20, 20);

        doc.setTextColor(150);
        doc.text("This is light gray.", 20, 30);

        doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
        doc.text("This is red.", 20, 40);

        doc.setTextColor(0, 255, 0);
        doc.text("This is green.", 20, 50);
        doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 255);
        doc.text("This is blue.", 20, 60);

        doc.setTextColor("red");
        doc.text("This is red.", 60, 40);

        doc.setTextColor("green");
        doc.text("This is green.", 60, 50);

        doc.setTextColor("blue");
        doc.text("This is blue.", 60, 60);      
        doc.autoPrint();
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting

Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined  ace.js:37
Uncaught ReferenceError: ace is not defined  editot.js.28

I am trying this as a test before the doing the actual page but ut isn't working

Any idea what is wrong please
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Create PDF</title>      
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/examples/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
           <script src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/jspdf.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/addimage.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/from_html.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/ie_below_9_shim.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/svg.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jspdf/jsPDF-1.3.2/plugins/autoprint.js">
      </script>
    

  </head>

  <body>
      <script>
    
          var doc = new jsPDF();
          var name = "Doe, John"
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.setFontSize(12);
          doc.text(20,20,'Name: '+ name);
          doc.autoPrint();
          window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
      </script>
 </body>
```